# Create a quotient-lifted type with polymorphism over working set and equivalence relation in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: set, higher-order-functions, isabelle, theorem-proving, isar

I would like to create a quotient type with `quotient_type` in Isabelle/HOL in which I would left "non-constructed" the non-empty set `S` and the equivalence relation `≡`. The goal is for me to derive **generic** properties w.r.t. `S` and `≡` over the quotient-lifted set `S/≡`. In this way, it would be interesting that Isabelle/HOL accepts [*dependent types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type)... But I was told that was not possible.

Hence, I tried this

```
(* 1. Defining an arbitrary set and its associated type *)
consts S :: "'a set"
typedef ('a) inst = "{ x :: 'a. ¬ S = ({} :: 'a set) ⟶ x ∈ S}" by(auto)

(* 2. Defining the equivalence relation *)
definition equiv :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" where
  "equiv x y = undefined"
  (* here needs a property of equivalence relationship... *)

(* 3. Defining the quotiented set *)
quotient_type ('a) quotiented_set = "('a inst × 'a inst)" / "equiv"
(* Hence, impossible end proof here... *)
```

Is this formalization, there appears to be two problems

1. I don't think this is the *cleanest* way to define an arbitrary set `S` as I can't specify it to be non-empty...
2. I can't define an arbitrary equivalence relation `equiv` with the `definition` nor the `fun` commands as they only allow me define "constructive-strongly normalizing-inductive" definitions only... And yet, I want to say that I **just** have some function `equiv` that satisfies properties of equivalence (reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity).

Do you have any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOL types cannot depend on values. So if you want to define a quotient type for an arbitrary non-empty set `S` and equivalence relation `equiv` using `quotient_type`, the arbitrary part must stay at the meta-level. Thus, `S` and `equiv` can either be axiomatized or defined such that you can convince yourself that you really have captured the desired notion of arbitrary.

If you axiomatize `S` and `equiv`, then you yourself are responsible that the axioms are consistent with the other axioms of HOL. You can do that with the command `axiomatization` as in

```
axiomatization S :: "'a set" where S_not_empty: "S ≠ {}"
```

For Isabelle/HOL, `S` is then a fixed constant of which you only know that it is not empty. You will never be able to instantiate `S`, because the arbitrariness only exists in the set-theoretic interpretation of Isabelle/HOL.

If you do not want to add new axioms, you can use `specification` instead:

```
consts S :: "'a set"
specification (S) S_not_empty: "S ≠ {}" by auto
```

With `specification`, you have to prove that your axioms are consistent, so there is no danger here. However, `S` no longer is absolutely arbitrary, because it is defined in terms of the choice operator `Eps`, as can be seen from the generated theorem `S_def`.

If you really want to study the theory of quotients within Isabelle/HOL, I recommend that you do not use types, but ordinary sets. There is the quotient operator `op //` and some theorems in the theory `Equiv_Relations` which is part of the library.